# Git pretty format: Conditionally insert text

Tags: git

[`git-log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) says that:

> **PRETTY FORMATS.**  If the commit is a merge, and if the pretty-format is not oneline, email or raw, an additional line is inserted before the Author: line. This line begins with "Merge: " and the hashes of ancestral commits are printed, separated by spaces.

However, this is only true of the built-in pretty formats.  I'd therefore like to explicitly put in a `Merge: %p%n` line, but only for commits with multiple parents.

Is this possible?